# Git three-way merge with conflict noob issue reading the book

Tags: git, version-control, branch, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I'm just started learning git version control and I'm facing this problem. Given the following branch structure (taken from the free [book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging)):

[image: branch structure]

Let's assume that C4/C5 commits changed the same part of `index.html` file.

```
git checkout master
git merge iss53
```

If I understand it correclty I need to solve the conflict manually. The book says something about a conflict file. Where is this conflict file? And how, given the following conflict:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD:index.html
<div id="footer">contact : email.support@github.com</div>
=======
<div id="footer">
  please contact us at support@github.com
</div>
>>>>>>> iss53:index.html
```

can I discard all changes from HEAD, merging only changes from "iss53" branch into "master"? How to edit these lines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The conflicting lines will be in the file with the conflict.  So if your index.html file has conflicts, you can just open it in a text editor to get the view you have above.

You'll want to delete the lines you don't need (and/or make changes), then save the file.  Then `git add index.html`, and `git merge --continue`.

Alternatively, look into using `git mergetool` http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-mergetool.html

Comment: That is, I just need to remove the markers like `<<<<<` and those changes that I don't need?

Answer (score 3):

> The book says something about a conflict file. Where is this conflict file?

There is no "conflict file", there are only files, and they may be *in conflict* if both parents of a merge have made changes to a file which can't be merged automatically. In this case, you need to manually resolve the conflicts by editing the file, or (see below) by checking out one of the two parent versions of the file.

> And how... can I discard all changes from HEAD, merging only changes from "iss53" branch into "master"?

During a merge, you can use `git checkout --theirs index.html` to throw away your changes and use the version being merged in. After doing so, the file will still be marked as in-conflict, and you'll have to `git add index.html` to mark the conflict as resolved.